# Accessing a variable from another script C# UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two script 
**simplecloudhander.cs
cloudtarget.cs**

simplecloudhander.cs

```
public string mTargetMetadata = "";

public void OnNewSearchResult(TargetFinder.TargetSearchResult targetSearchResult)
    {

        GameObject newImageTarget = Instantiate(ImageTargetTemplate.gameObject) as GameObject;

        GameObject augmentation = null;

        string model_name = targetSearchResult.MetaData;


        if( augmentation != null )
            augmentation.transform.parent = newImageTarget.transform;


        ImageTargetAbstractBehaviour imageTargetBehaviour = mImageTracker.TargetFinder.EnableTracking(targetSearchResult, newImageTarget);

        Debug.Log("Metadata value is " + model_name );
        mTargetMetadata = model_name;
}
```

i want to access **mTargetMetadata** value in another **cloudtarget.cs script**

here cloudtarget.cs script

```
void OnGUI() {
        SimpleCloudHandler sc = new SimpleCloudHandler ();

        GUI.Label (new Rect(100,300,300,50), "Metadata: " + sc.mTargetMetadata);

}
```

but i can't get mTargetMetadata value in another script

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a reference to that script in the **cloudtarget** script. Just add a public variable of type **SimpleCloudHandler** to the class **cloudtarget**, not on the OnGUI method, later drag and drop the GameObject with the **SimpleCloudHandler** atached to the script **cloudtarget** in the inspector.

Example:

[image]
[image]

Drag and drop the MainCamera with the SimpleCloudHandler script attached => to the public **SimpleCloudHandler** variable of the **cloudtarget** script through the inspector.

There are multiple ways to make a reference in Unity, I recommend you to look to the documentation that Unity offer

Comment: thanx sir but i can't problem slove rignt nw

Answer (score 0):

if your scripts are attached to the same object then you can use `GetComponent`like this,

```
gameObject.GetComponent<simplecloudhander>().mTargetMetadata
```

if they are not attached to the same `gameObject`the you can use `GameObject.Find` first to find the `gameObject` that the script is attached to, you should use the name of the `gameObject` to find it, then use the `GetComponent` to get the `component`that you want

```
GameObject.Find("nameOftheGameObject").GetComponent<simplecloudhander>().mTargetMetadata
```

also there is no need for new keyword, if you just want to access it,

```
 simplecloudhander sch;

    void Start()
    {
     sch = GameObject.Find("nameOftheGameObject").GetComponent<simplecloudhander>();
    }
    void OnGUI() {
            GUI.Label (new Rect(100,300,300,50), "Metadata: " + sch .mTargetMetadata);

    }
```

Comment: thanxx sir i try it but its don't retrive it

Comment: thanxx sir i try it but its don't retrive it

void OnGUI() 
{
 
SimpleCloudHandler sc = new SimpleCloudHandler ();
 
a= GameObject.Find ("mTargetMetadata").GetComponents<SimpleCloudHandler>().ToString();

GUI.Label (new Rect(100,300,300,50), "Metadata: " + a);

}

Comment: you shouldnt call it in `OnGUI` , I edited to show you where it should be called, also is `mTargetMetadata` also the name of your gameobject?

Comment: https://www.datafilehost.com/d/c1f60b49

https://www.datafilehost.com/d/3386727d



i already here two file

1.SimpleCloudHandler.cs

2.VideoPlaybackBehaviour.cs


in 1st file simplecloudhandler.cs connect  with vuforia cloud database 

and when imagetarget scan and it show 3D object also show meta data value in GUI LABEL 

it's work

bt i want to first scirpt in metadata value (mTargetMetadata) access in second script and display using GUIlable